# Firefox and Thunderbird unable to find active network connection

Tags: networking

Driver: rtl8821ac
Hardware address: DC:85:DE:CB:9F:1F
Default route: 192.168.0.1

Comment: Is it only Firefox and Thunderbird that are having issues connecting to the internet? Can you open a terminal and run something like `ping -c 3 www.google.com` and post the output? Perhaps an `ip link` would also be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Had to reinstall Windows as I had deleted all the drivers when installing Ubuntu. Now they work OK on a dual boot installation.

Comment: Still Having problems connecting to the WiFi:

Output Wired Connection:

thomas@thomas:~$ ping -c 3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (24.244.19.181) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 24.244.19.181: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=29.3 ms
64 bytes from 24.244.19.181: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=19.1 ms
64 bytes from 24.244.19.181: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=29.5 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.172/26.013/29.527/4.841 ms

Comment: Output below is from the Wireless Connection; Wired Connection Disabled:

thomas@thomas:~$ ping -c 3 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com